# How to access same post from one controller to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to Full Stack web development. Right now I encountered a problem. I am using mongodb, mongoose, node and express.

I have two controllers, one is signup, and another one is profile.

code for signup will be like this

```
router.post('/',(req,res,next)=>{

    let user = new userProfile();
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.name = req.body.firstName;

    user.save((err)=>{
        if(err){
            return err;
        }
    })
    res.redirect('/profile');
});
```

After click submit, I can find the user entry in the collection. Now I am at profile controller.

The code for profile:

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.email);
    userProfile.find({email: 'yyyy'},(err,user)=>{
        if(err) return err;

    })
    res.render('profile/profile');  
})
```

When I do the console.log, it outputs undefined. The expected output should be the email address from signup page, so that when I do find function, I will get the correct entry with same email address and display corresponding username on the webpage.

My question is how can profile controller access the same post infor from signup controller.

Comment: The `req` object is only scoped to the "current request" which means if you actually did not send anything in the "body" of that request then there is nothing there. You actually don't work with a "body" in a GET request anyway. Rather you would either send the data in the url and match in the request as `router.get('/:email',(req,res) => { userProfile.findOne({ "email": req.params.email },...` or you would in fact rather use "sessions" and retrieve the current authenticated user through that instead. Perhaps look at [passport](http://passportjs.org/docs) as a way to integrate authentication.

Comment: It sounds like you need a user session on the server so once the user is logged in on the first request, when the second request comes in, you can tell which user it is.  http servers are basically stateless so you don't directly access data from one request in another request as that first request is long gone when the second request arrives.  Instead, you cookie the user and can then use code that implements a session object to store semi-persistent data for that particular user which can be accessed on future requests.  See [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that you use a middleware like bodyParser in Express. Otherwise your post request with `req.body` wouldn't work.

In a `router.get()` request you do not have any body. You can use a route like this:

`http://yourdomain.com/api/profile/test@mail.com` with:

```
router.get('/profile/:email',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.query.email);
    userProfile.find({email: req.query.email},(err,user)=> {
    [...]
}
```

or with params:

`http://yourdomain.com/api/profile/?email=test@mail.com` with:

```
router.get('/profile/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.params.email);
    userProfile.find({email: req.params.email},(err,user)=> {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is called Express middleware.

There's a great article here that gives an in-depth explanation with tons of examples of middleware on the application-level and
router-level.

In your case, your Express routing configuration should look something like the following,

```
// Controller containing your router.get (signup) and router.post (show profile) code
var core = require('../controllers/core.controller');

app.route('/signup')
  .post(core.signup, core.showProfile)
```

You can see that we've delegated the `POST /signup` path to first call core.signup, then core.showProfile (only if `next()` is called).

The two endpoint handlers you included in your original post will now be something like the following,

```
export.signup = (req,res) => {
    let user = new userProfile();
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.name = req.body.firstName;

    user.save((err)=>{
        if(err){
            return err;
        }
    })
    next();
});

export.showProfile = (req,res ) => {
    console.log(req.body.email);
    userProfile.find({email: 'yyyy'},(err,user)=>{
        if(err) return err;

    })
    res.render('profile/profile');  
})
```

These would live in whichever file you imported in your app route, which for example, I imported from path `../controllers/core.controller`.